# buffer menu unsort entries

Tags: buffers, customize, menus

Where can I handle how the `control + left-click` menu displays entries?

This is how it looks when it is displayed the way I want, i.e. with no fancy sorting by file type:

[image]

And this is how it looks when it tries to sort files for me...

[image]

It randomly toggles after a number of files are opened...

Comment: Have a look at customizing the variables `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult` and `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-groups` -- to see the doc-string, type `M-x describe-variable`

Comment: interesting comment lawlist. Does this mean that if I delete (or comment out) entries from that menu I won't get bothered by the sorting any more? This can be a nice workaround to my problem.:)

Comment: The doc-string for the first variable suggests setting the value to a high number.  Setting the latter variable to `nil` may case an error because there is a `dolist` that iterates through it.

Comment: if you post the fist comment as an answer I will accept it as a solution to my problem.:) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse buffer menu has a few customizable variables, a couple of which are `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult` and `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-groups`.  The default value for `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult` is `4`, so setting it to a higher value seems appropriate in this case -- e.g., a number high enough that grouping will not occur.

To read the doc-string for a variable, type `M-x describe-variable`.

To customize the variable, type `M-x customize-variable`.

The seemingly randomness of grouping (sometimes yes, sometimes no) indicates a bug.  Someone who is motivated may wish to submit a bug report in relation thereto.

Comment: lawlist: "Someone who is motivated may wish to submit a bug report in relation thereto." how to do this?

Comment: Emacs has the built-in email address and it gathers information about your setup when you type `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Reporting a bug is an investment of time, because the Emacs team may respond by asking for clarification how to reproduce the behavior.  And, the Emacs team may ask for the individual to test proposed solutions.  Depending on the complexity of the bug, it could potentially be a lot of time invested.  However, sometimes it is simple.  I generally include a recipe starting from no user-configuration (what we call `emacs -q`) and state what I expected and what happened.

Comment: You are an emacs pro lawlist!:) OK, I think I don't have the luxury of investing such time to report this minor hiccup. Your proposed solution is good enough for me.